# How to fix "Stray end tag head." and "Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open." in HTML

Tags: html

Multiple HTML checkers are giving me these errors, but I do not understand how I am getting them or how to fix them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta name="author" content="text">
    <meta name="description" content="text">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="text">
    <link rel="icon" href="image.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <title>text</title>
    <a href="./picturepage.html">text</a>
  </head>

  <body>
```

Comment: This usually indicates that an element that belongs in the body was found somewhere in the head, thereby prematurely ending the head and starting the body. Can we see everything from the start of the document to the <body> start tag? Can we also see the answer you looked at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The end tag for `head` is optional
- The start tag for `body` is optional
- The `a` element is forbidden inside the `head`

Therefore your `a` element implicitly ends the `head` and starts the `body` so your `</head>` tag has no open `head` element to match.